# node express.Router().route() vs express.route()

Tags: node.js, express, routes

What should I use:

```
express.Router().route()
```

or

```
express.route()
```

?

Is it true `express.Router().route()` is someway deprecated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the current version of Express, you should use `express.Router().route()`. See the express [documentation](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#router.route) for confirmation. `express.Router().route()` is not depreciated.

For example:

```
var router = express.Router();

router.param('user_id', function(req, res, next, id) {
  // sample user, would actually fetch from DB, etc...
  req.user = {
    id: id,
    name: 'TJ'
  };
  next();
});

router.route('/users/:user_id')
.all(function(req, res, next) {
  // runs for all HTTP verbs first
  // think of it as route specific middleware!
  next();
})
.get(function(req, res, next) {
  res.json(req.user);
})
.put(function(req, res, next) {
  // just an example of maybe updating the user
  req.user.name = req.params.name;
  // save user ... etc
  res.json(req.user);
})
.post(function(req, res, next) {
  next(new Error('not implemented'));
})
.delete(function(req, res, next) {
  next(new Error('not implemented'));
})
```

Comment: Thanks... One more doubt: can I use an `:optionalParameter` with `express.Router().route()` ? I can't find it in the docs... app.route() can do it, using '?' after the param name...

Comment: Yes it can handle that

Answer (score 3):

Router.route() can use for chainable routes.
Meaning: You have one API for all the METHODS, you can write that in .route().

```
    var app = express.Router();
    app.route('/test')
      .get(function (req, res) {
         //code
      })
      .post(function (req, res) {
        //code
      })
      .put(function (req, res) {
        //code
      })
```